# Use angular ng-model ,Can not get the default value of radio

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

when the current form submission，when clicked, you can get the value of the value, but no click can not be obtained，I have already set up the initial value

```
<form class="form-css" name="myForm" novalidate>
    <label class="ar-l" for="sex">sex：</label>
    <input ng-model="user.sex" type="radio" name="sex" value="2" ng-checked="true">
    <i class="ar-l">male</i>
    <input ng-model="user.sex" type="radio" name="sex" value="3">
    <i class="ar-l">female</i>                                          
    <input ng-model="user.sex" type="radio" name="sex" value="1">
    <i class="ar-l">Confidentiality</i> 
    <div ng-click="saveData(myForm,user)">submit</div>              
</form>
```

[image]

The default display is correct, but not the time to submit the form to the initial value
     //submit js code

```
$scope.saveData = function(myForm, user) {
    console.log(user);    // undefined   
    KoudaidayService.saveUserMessage({sex: user.sex}).then(function(data) {
        something...
    });        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked

> Sets the checked attribute on the element, if the expression inside
>   ngChecked is truthy.
>
> Note that this directive should not be used together with ngModel, as
>   this can lead to unexpected behavior.

To fix it, just set the value of $scope.user.sex, and remove ng-checked